# Vuetify: Button dropdown with multiple selections (checkboxes)

Tags: vuetify.js

I want a button that opens a dropdown list with multiple items that are selectable. Another way to see it is that I want a v-select component with the multiple property, but replacing the v-select input field with a button.

I have seen a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-resonance-nosgh?file=/src/components/Playground.vue:882-1184). However, when I try to re-create it using the latest Vuetify version, it does not work as expected, as the v-select input is showing. How can I solve this? :)

Code ([Playground link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)):

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-btn
        @click="toggleSelect = !toggleSelect"
        :color="`${toggleSelect ? 'primary':'none'}`"
      >
        Open
      </v-btn>
      <v-select
        :items="items"
        multiple
        item-title="text"
        item-value="value"
        v-if="toggleSelect"
        v-model="selectedItems"
        :menu-props="{value: toggleSelect}"
        return-object
        hide-details
      ></v-select>

      <br />
      {{ selectedItemsTitles }}
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { computed, ref, watch } from 'vue'

  const toggleSelect = ref(false)
  const selectedItems = ref([])
  const selectedItemsTitles = computed(() =>
    selectedItems.value.map(i => i.text).join(', ')
  )
  const items = [
    { text: 'Dessert (100g serving)', value: 'name' },
    { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
    { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
  ]
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a custom activator on the underlying v-menu using its [`:activator`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#props-activator) prop, passing in a template ref from the v-btn works. Since it is a button, the [`:open-on-click`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#props-open-on-click) prop is also necessary. Put those into v-select's [`:menu-props`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-menu-props) so that it passes them on to the v-menu. Now the menu opens below the button when you click it. Now you can hide the v-text-field from the v-select by a plain CSS `display:none` or by setting `v-show="false"` (make sure Vue still renders the it, otherwise the v-menu will be gone too).

```html
<v-btn ref="toggleSelectButton"> Open </v-btn>
<v-select
  :menu-props="{
    activator: toggleSelectButton,
    openOnClick: true,
  }"
  v-show="false"
  ...
```

and (in composition API):

```js
const toggleSelectButton = ref()
```

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)